Flutter Windows Build error RC2176 on Jenkins
I have a flutter windows project, that I am building in Jenkins using my own Gradle plugin that just calls the flutter binary.
But when building the windows application I am getting the following error log:
> Task :flutter_app:flutterBuildWindows

Building Windows application...                                 

C:\Jenkins\workspace\eature_51-verification-deep-link\flutter_app\windows\runner\Runner.rc(55): error RC2176: old DIB in resources\app_icon.ico; pass it through SDKPAINT [C:\Jenkins\workspace\eature_51-verification-deep-link\flutter_app\build\windows\x64\runner\flutter_app.vcxproj]

Building Windows application...                                   111.6s

Build process failed.


> Task :flutter_app_vet_console:flutterBuildWindows FAILED


What really confuses my about this is that on my local machine it works perfectly fine.
I also found this Stackoverflow Question and tried the accepted solution using GIMP, but that didn't fix my error.
Has anybody any idea what could be causing this?
The Visual Studio version in the flutter doctor command is the same on my local machine and on my Jenkins Windows Agent.
